# Trying to recreate graphic from image as a vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I am trying to recreate the rings from the following image into a vector graphic. I have made several attempts using various shapes and the pen tool with no luck. Any help on which steps I could take would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the image in question (on [pinterest](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/426223552209457681/)):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You simply draw one ellipse.
- Duplicate it.
- Draw a rectangle for the sides.
- Then use the **Shape Builder Tool** to combine specific pieces (Holding the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down with the Shape Builder Tool will *remove* parts.)
- Then add color.

[image: Ring Creation Animation]

Comment: Holy cats! Remind me again why we haven't renamed the site Scott and Alan Stack Exchange?

Comment: Scott your original anim was better